# How to do a gold / metal static look in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, linear-gradients, flutter-design

I would like to apply some effects on Icons and Cards to get a gold look like on the picture. I assume we would need a [LinearGradient](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/LinearGradient-class.html) and a shadow with another LinearGradient, or perhaps a Stack with a second icon that is slightly larger with a darker LinearGradient. What would be the best way to go about it? I am also aware of the https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer plugin but that is animated, and I am looking for sg static.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can use a container and give it a linear gradient color and add some boreders and it should look like the picture

here is an example:

```
Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 125,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: 5.0,
            ),
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Colors.yellow, Color(0xffad9c00)],
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```